# Bootstrap container background can only be white or some other color/image but not transparent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, transparency

Every text element in my html file either inside the bootstrap's container or another div will not be transparent from what I've tried: background:transparent !important, background-color with rgba opacity, and adding opacity itself.

Here's the HTML + CSS:

```
html { 
    background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "elephant";
  src: url("elephnt.ttf");
}

#frontpage{
  background: transparent; 
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}
#title
{
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-size: 50px;
text-shadow: rgb(3, 3, 3) -1px 4px 9px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background:transparent;" >


 <h1 id="title">Butt</h1>


</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So your background image is not visible. correct?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers correct for me ... Does this make a difference? How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a default background color of white specificied

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff; /* here */
}
```

You need to override that.

```css
html {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/fashion-q-c-640-480-8.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "elephant";
  src: url("elephnt.ttf");
}
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}
#title {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: rgb(3, 3, 3) -1px 4px 9px;
}
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  /* important used here for demo */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">


  <h1 id="title">Butt</h1>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rt673zjh/)

CSS

```
 body{background:#666;}
 #title{
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 50px;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container-fluid" style="background:transparent;" >
 <h1 id="title">Butt</h1>
 </div>
```